# Ways to make an app run continuously in android watch?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am looking for ways to keep an android app in watch to run in background continuously. Links/methods to do this will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance. I would also like to know more about this.

Comment: You need to elaborate what you want to achieve; running a background service/app continuously is a very bad idea, specially on a device with such a limited resources. If you explain what your goal is, we may be able to offer a better solution for you.

Comment: Hi, I have developed gesture recognition app. Now I want the app to run in background in the watch so that watch can constantly communicate with the mobile(recognize and send the gesture details). We basically don't want the user to touch the screen again and again to open the app in watch.

Comment: What type of gestures are you thinking about?

Comment: Mainly accelerometer, gyro based non touch gestures. It could be both one hand and two hands gestures. Android watches worn on the user's hands recognize the gestures performed and communicates to the mobile.

Comment: Continuously reading sensors on a wear device is *very* expensive, can easily kill your battery in no time so you should avoid that. These types of things should only be done by the framework and not by a third-party app.

Answer (score -1):

Use WearableListenerService to run app in background.

Comment: That is an incorrect answer. WearableListenerService has a completely different purpose and doesn't cause the app to run continuously (which it shouldn't). Running any app/service in the background continuously is a very bad idea as well.